# Project refresh failed Error:exception during working with external system: - Android Studio 2.1 Preview

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I updated the Android Studio to Preview 2.1 and the gradle is updated as well

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.0-alpha1'
}
```

I got this message :

[image: test]

When i click on the ***Try Again*** shown upside, i get this message

```
Gradle 'TestProject' Project refresh failed
  Error:exception during working with external system:
```

Anybody faced and solved this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

change classpath to

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```